# Shuffling through list items on mouseover with Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseover

Ok, guys, I am trying to replicate this effect: http://lab.hakim.se/kort/
Basically, I have an ul with 10 absolutely positioned list items. Since, the last list item is always on top, I know that I am hovering on it and want to move the rest of the lis to the right or left, depending on whether they are odd or even. I am trying to achieve a detection for this like so:

```
function reshuffleCards(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'LI') {
    if (e.target == e.target.parentNode.children[9]) {
      e.target.className = 'active';
    } else {
      var oddItems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li:nth-child(odd)');
      oddItems.style.webkitTransform = 'translateY(-100px)';  
    }
  }
}
```

I guess that this is not the most elegant solution to the problem, so any comments and suggestions are more then welcome.

Here's a link to my pen:
http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/rLzwo

Comment: Why you attach `mouseover` listener to document? Why not to list items?

Comment: Why are you trying to replicate it? That project is **open source** on Github...

Comment: For the practice I guess

Answer (score 0):

I'd do all transitions with css, something like this:

```
$('#perspective').on('mousemove', function(e) {
   var x = e.pageX,
       w = $(this).outerWidth(),
       lis = $(this).children('li'),
       child = Math.floor(x/w * lis.size()/2);

   lis.removeClass('active');
   $(this).children('li:nth(' + child + ')').addClass('active');
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nCqFa

Or even more — swipe cards with hover: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pnlrd